Operational amplifier layout- Controlled impedance
In the following picture, we can see a reference layout by Texas instrument for OPA838:

I noticed, in the polygon on the top layer, they have used a specific gap=0.5 mm, I wonder if they used a control impedance routing (50 Ohm) for the input and output? and should I consider the same approach for my layout? (I will use OPA838, OPA837), is this a general practice for routing operation amplifier? or it is necessary?

The TLV3011 is a comparator, not an OpAmp. Did you mean a different chip?

@ Jonathan S I asked TI to share a reference design for operational amplifier, and they shared this with me.

@  Jonathan S it seems the pinout is totally the same with OPA838

At those frequencies, you don't need controlled impedance for that length. That looks like their default 'easy to make' gaps for evaluation boards. The AD838 does not have 50 ohm I/Os, you would not use 50 ohm tracks to connect to it. The main thing with opamps, especially quick ones, is low capacitance I/O tracking. I would expect the components connected between op-amp and I/O connectors, a schematic of which you have not shared, have more to do with testing, and using 50 ohm test equipment, than they have to do with the operation of the op-amp.

Please can you link to the document that the image came from.

@ Andy aka There is no direct link for this, I got this directly from TI by requesting via email and they sent me the file.

You can find a similar reference layout that is specific to the OPA838 here: https://www.ti.com/lit/ug/slou474/slou474.pdf.  My guess is that the gap is just to reduce surface leakage currents (from power nets into or out of the sensitive signal traces). The datasheet also has layout recommendations, which don't talk about impedance matching: https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/opa838.pdf.
